# Is std::memory_order_relaxed enough for checking "Availability"?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, memory-barriers

I have a concurrent object that might or might hold pointer to function at every single time. A schema of the object looks like:

```
struct ConcurrentObject{
  //variables
  std::atomic<void(*)()> callback;
}
```

so one thread may decide he want to attach callback with this object and pass it forward:

```
ConcurrentObject* co = new ConcurrentObject(); //I'm using smart pointers, no worries.
//do some logic
co->callback = someCallback; //void(*)() , this may be difference callback every time
```

I get this object after it went modification and check if a callback is available:

```
auto co = aquireConcurrentObject();
auto callback = co->callback.load();
if (callback){
    callback()
}
```

now, we know that without specifying any memory order the default memory ordered passed is `memory_order_seq_cst` which tells the compiler (in a nutshell) "do not scrumble any read or write instruction to make the program faster, keep the relative order of instruction as specied by the code, and make it visible through the cpu's".

we also know it a great performance obsticale, since the compiler is much more limited with the action it can take.

My question is - does `std::memory_order_relaxed` is enough for this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct, in your example std::memory_order_relaxed is safe to use because your code rely only on the fact that callback is atomic. Your code is not affected by possible reorder of memory operations

Answer (score 1):

Memory order for callback pointer accesses affects on "visibility" of variables, used by the callback.

If your callback:

1) is *constexpr*-like, that is it doesn't use anything except its arguments and constant global variables, or

2) uses only variables, which are *initialized* before (*happens-before*) possible usage of callback,

then using `std::memory_order_relaxed` is OK for both store and load.

But if your code under `//do some logic` initializes some variables, used by the callback, then you should use *at least* `std::memory_order_release`/`std::memory_order_acquire` for store and load correspondigly. Otherwise, execution of callback may see these variable uninitialized (more scrictly, it will be *data race* from the sence of C++11 standard, which is Undefined Behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a way to measure the performance impact? Changing the memory order might look like a good performance boot here (It seems valid), but really, in most applications - it would not matter.

Changing the memory model here means that anyone who would maintain this code will need to be extra careful not to break it, so that's another risk you have take when doing this kind of things.

Such optimizations **needs to be very well documented and chosen after it had been proven of being a performance bottleneck**. Do not mess with it if you don't have to.

Comment: this is more suitable as a comment, since you are not explicitly answering the question. anyway, it may not be the bottleneck, but it can reduce performance in general, and you can measue the program with and without using std::memory_order_relaxed to see how much is affected. my question is can I even do that in order to profile correct program and not buggish program.